# Calculate sum based on nested filter

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

**The problem**

This works as expected and produces the result with the `totalpax` field being correct. However, the `pax` field for each destination, should be the sum based on the destination Id.

**Code**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ReservationCalendarGroupVM>> GetForCalendarAsync(string fromDate, string toDate) {
        return await context.Schedules
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) && x.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(toDate))
            .GroupBy(z => new { z.Date })
            .Select(e => new ReservationCalendarGroupVM {
                Date = e.Key.Date.ToString(),
                Destinations = e.GroupBy(i => new { i.Destination.Id, i.Destination.Abbreviation, i.Destination.Description }).Select(p => new DestinationCalendarVM {
                    Id = p.Key.Id,
                    Abbreviation = p.Key.Abbreviation,
                    Description = p.Key.Description,
                    Pax = context.Reservations.Where(y => y.Date == e.Key.Date).Sum(h => h.TotalPersons)
                }),
                TotalPax = context.Reservations.Where(y => y.Date == e.Key.Date).Sum(h => h.TotalPersons).ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Result**

```
"date": "2022-07-02",
"destinations": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "PAXOS - ANTIPAXOS",
        "abbreviation": "PA",
        "pax": 254
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "BLUE LAGOON",
        "abbreviation": "BL",
        "pax": 254
    }
],
"totalpax": 432
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in this line:

```
Pax = context.Reservations.Where(y => y.Date == e.Key.Date).Sum(h => h.TotalPersons)
```

You're filtering exclusively by Date, but you need to filter simultaneously by Destination. As you didn't share the models it's not very easy to infer, but I believe you'll need to do the following:

```
Pax = context.Reservations
    .Where(y => y.Date == e.Key.Date && y.Destination.Id == e.Key.Id).Sum(h => h.TotalPersons)
```